# How to parse logic as text into a data structure

Tags: php, data-structures, lexical-analysis

Given the string

```
{A} AND ({B} OR {C} OR ({D} AND {E}))
```

How can this be parsed to be in a usable data structure?

I currently have

```
$tokens = preg_split(
    '/( AND | OR |\)|\()/',
    $rules[0]['option_rule'],
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
);

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (empty($token)) {
        continue;
    }

    $token = trim($token);

    $special = ['(', ')', 'AND', 'OR'];

    // do something with the token?

}
```

But have no idea how to go about handling the multiple levels.

Comment: You could create a tree like structure where each node has a operator (AND/OR) and a truth value associated with it

Answer (score 0):

somethink like that might work, 1 = AND, 0 = OR

```
array(
    '{A}' => 1,
    array(
        '{B}' => 0,
        '{C}' => 0,
        array(
            '{D}' => 1,
            '{E}' =>
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be to specify your grammar rules and create a lexer that can process/parse a text using the grammar. For example: http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP